# The video recording device is preempted by another immersive application

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

Am I opening the camera for taking a picture, but the user has the possibility to stop the camera if he no longer wants to capture something, so I have a close button which is intended to close the camera, so that the camera preview should be stopped.

If I open the camera, close, open again, I will get the following exception once the close button is clicked for the second time:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The video recording device is preempted by another immersive application.
```

I do not know, how the preview camera should be stopped, more than UWP docs say here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/simple-camera-preview-access

The code for stopping the camera preview:

```
private async Task CleanupCameraAsync()
    {
        if (_mediaCapture != null)
        {
            if (_isPreviewing)
            {
                await _mediaCapture.StopPreviewAsync();
            }

            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                CameraPreviewControl.Source = null;
                if (_displayRequest != null)
                {
                    _displayRequest.RequestRelease();
                }

                _mediaCapture.Dispose();
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to test your code snippet on my side and it can work well. I didn't get the above exception. I tested on the emulator build 15063 and build 14393. Since your code snippet is not the completed code, so I created a minimal project for testing as follows which can work well on my side. You may test it on your side and compare with your code if something wrong with your project.

XAML

```
<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Padding="30"> 
   <CaptureElement Name="PreviewControl" Stretch="Uniform"/>
   <Button x:Name="btnpreview" Click="btnpreview_Click" Content="preview test"></Button>
   <Button x:Name="btnstop" Click="btnstop_Click" Content="stop"></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind

```
private DeviceInformation _cameraDevice;
private MediaCapture _mediaCapture;
private InMemoryRandomAccessStream _ras;
private LowLagMediaRecording _recording;
private CameraRotationHelper _rotationHelper;
private readonly DisplayRequest _displayRequest = new DisplayRequest();
private bool _isPreviewing; 

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
}
private async void btnstop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    if (_mediaCapture != null)
    {
        if (_isPreviewing)
        {
            await _mediaCapture.StopPreviewAsync();
            _isPreviewing = false;
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                PreviewControl.Source = null;
                if (_displayRequest != null)
                {
                    _displayRequest.RequestRelease();
                }
            _mediaCapture.Dispose();
            });
        }
    }
} 
private async void btnpreview_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        _mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
        var allVideoDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);
        var desiredDevice = allVideoDevices.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EnclosureLocation != null && x.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back);
        _cameraDevice = desiredDevice ?? allVideoDevices.FirstOrDefault();
        _rotationHelper = new CameraRotationHelper(_cameraDevice.EnclosureLocation);
        _mediaCapture.Failed += MediaCapture_Failed;
        var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings { VideoDeviceId = _cameraDevice.Id };
        await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);   
        PreviewControl.Source = _mediaCapture;
        _displayRequest.RequestActive();
        await _mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
        _isPreviewing = true; 
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        // This will be thrown if the user denied access to the camera in privacy settings
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The app was denied access to the camera");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("MediaCapture initialization failed. {0}", ex.Message);
    }
}
```

If you still have issues, please provide a  minimal reproduced project and the testing environment information. More details please reference the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit).

Comment: I've forgot to mention that I open the camera screen in a different page which is in a popup element. And I send messages using MVVM light for start/stop, show/hide the camera screen.

Comment: @mbob which popup element? Did you mean [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup) element?  How you send "messages" using MVVM light? Without reproduce your issue, we could not help you.